# need help in specifying object in an android application

Tags: android

am new to android and am working on followers layout in my e-commerce application for a course project.i tried to upload a pic,but unfortunately i cant so am going to try my best in explaining what i need.

am trying to stat my implementation after i finished the prototype.what should each of the elements listed below be?
each follower includes:

1-a pic of the user.

2-a name.

3-a button to follow this user.

the over all layout is a list of followers with a button "back" and a "search" one.

thanks for help.

Comment: What is your question, exactly?

Comment: Did you meet the `ListView` already?

Comment: yes ,and it should be scrolable

Answer (score 0):

I hope I'm understanding your question correctly. The picture should be an ImageView, the name should be a TextView, and the button should be a Button.

Comment: exactly,but my question is how to implement a scroll list in android ? i need it in tow layouts,followers and following.

Comment: So you want to have a ListView containing all that info and you want it to scroll too?